# Dynamodb mapper unable to read when using @DBDocument annotation

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have an Entity class which has some strings/ints as member variable and a member variable whose type is Photo. I have defined Photo type as:

```
@DynamoDBDocument
public static class Photo {
    @DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "url")
    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }

    @DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "width")
    public Integer getWidth() {
        return width;
    }

    @DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "height")
    public Integer getHeight() {
        return height;
    }

    public void setUrl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }

    public void setWidth(Integer width) {
        this.width = width;
    }

    public void setHeight(Integer height) {
        this.height = height;
    }

    private String url;
    private Integer width;
    private Integer height;

    public Photo(String url, Integer width, Integer height) {
        this.url = url;
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
    }
}
```

When I try to write an Entity object, I can see the Photo type is stored as a map (M).

But when I try read from dynamo the same entity, it gives exception:

```
com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBMappingException: PostingPhotoEntity[detail]; could not unconvert attribute
```

If I have to define the convert/unconvert for Photo, then what is the use of @DBDocument annotation. I had thought it can also deserialize the data from table.

Please help!

Answer (score 3):

I had to define a default constructor for Photo

```
public Photo() { }
```